# Decrease execution time of SQl select query in Android

Tags: android, sql, performance, sqlite

I am trying to use stand alone **SQLite database** from my android code so I have decided to use `SQLiteAssetHelper` for this. I have created my class that `extends SQLiteAssetsHelper` and have written few methods for getting data from SQLite database. Every one of this methods create a database connection to db and retrieve the value from database using Cursor. The value is single it is not the set of data, but the **sql** query is a little bit heavy, something like this

```
select 
round(
sum(cnt / 1000 * price + 
    cnt_arm / 1000 * price_arm1 + 
    cnt_arm / 1000 * price_arm2 + 
    cnt_arm / 1000 * price_arm3)
, 2) price 
from (
select ifnull((2000.0 + 2 * o1.w7), 0) cnt, 
ifnull((2000.0 - 2 * o1.kor_wzm45), 0) cnt_arm, (w1.kurs / 10000) * nh1.info price, ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm1.info, 0) price_arm1, 
ifnull((w_arm2.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm2.info, 0) price_arm2, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm3.info, 0) price_arm3, 
osciez1 nr_art_prof, nh1.nazwa, nh1.waluta 
from typyp t1 
inner join Osciezp o1 on t1.osciez1 = o1.nr_art 
left join wzmocn wz1 on wz1.nr_art = o1.wzm1 and 'a' = 'a' 
left join wzmocn wz2 on wz2.nr_art = o1.wzm2 and 'a' = 'b' 
left join wzmocn wz3 on wz3.nr_art = o1.wzm3  and 'a' = 'c' 
inner join profhand ph1 on ph1.nr_art = o1.nr_art 
inner join koloryp k1 on k1.indeks = ph1.idx_koloru 
inner join nhandlo1 nh1 on nh1.nr_art = ph1.nr_art_han 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm1 on nh_arm1.nr_art = wz1.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm2 on nh_arm2.nr_art = wz2.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm3 on nh_arm3.nr_art = wz3.nr_art 
inner join waluty w1 on w1.nr_art = nh1.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm1 on w_arm1.nr_art = nh_arm1.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm2 on w_arm2.nr_art = nh_arm2.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm3 on w_arm3.nr_art = nh_arm3.waluta 
where t1.indeks = 1 and k1.indeks = 1   
union all  
select 
ifnull((1000.0 + 2 * o2.w7), 0) cnt, 
ifnull((1000.0 - 2 * o2.kor_wzm45), 0) cnt_arm, 
(w2.kurs / 10000) * nh2.info price, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm1.info, 0) price_arm1, 
ifnull((w_arm2.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm2.info, 0) price_arm2, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm3.info, 0) price_arm3, 
osciez2 nr_art_prof, nh2.nazwa, nh2.waluta 
from typyp t2 
inner join Osciezp o2 on t2.osciez2 = o2.nr_art 
left join wzmocn wz1 on wz1.nr_art = o2.wzm1 and 'a' = 'a' 
left join wzmocn wz2 on wz2.nr_art = o2.wzm2 and 'a' = 'b' 
left join wzmocn wz3 on wz3.nr_art = o2.wzm3   and 'a' = 'c' 
inner join profhand ph2 on ph2.nr_art = o2.nr_art 
inner join koloryp k2 on k2.indeks = ph2.idx_koloru 
inner join nhandlo1 nh2 on nh2.nr_art = ph2.nr_art_han 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm1 on nh_arm1.nr_art = wz1.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm2 on nh_arm2.nr_art = wz2.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm3 on nh_arm3.nr_art = wz3.nr_art 
inner join waluty w2 on w2.nr_art = nh2.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm1 on w_arm1.nr_art = nh_arm1.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm2 on w_arm2.nr_art = nh_arm2.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm3 on w_arm3.nr_art = nh_arm3.waluta 
where t2.indeks = 1 and k2.indeks = 1   
union all  
select 
ifnull((2000.0 + 2 * o3.w7), 0) cnt, 
ifnull((2000.0 - 2 * o3.kor_wzm45), 0) cnt_arm, 
(w3.kurs / 10000) * nh3.info price, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm1.info, 0) price_arm1, 
ifnull((w_arm2.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm2.info, 0) price_arm2, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm3.info, 0) price_arm3, 
osciez3 nr_art_prof, nh3.nazwa, nh3.waluta 
from typyp t3 
inner join Osciezp o3 on t3.osciez3 = o3.nr_art 
left join wzmocn wz1 on wz1.nr_art = o3.wzm1 and 'a' = 'a' 
left join wzmocn wz2 on wz2.nr_art = o3.wzm2 and 'a' = 'b' 
left join wzmocn wz3 on wz3.nr_art = o3.wzm3   and 'a' = 'c' 
inner join profhand ph3 on ph3.nr_art = o3.nr_art 
inner join koloryp k3 on k3.indeks = ph3.idx_koloru 
inner join nhandlo1 nh3 on nh3.nr_art = ph3.nr_art_han 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm1 on nh_arm1.nr_art = wz1.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm2 on nh_arm2.nr_art = wz2.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm3 on nh_arm3.nr_art = wz3.nr_art 
inner join waluty w3 on w3.nr_art = nh3.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm1 on w_arm1.nr_art = nh_arm1.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm2 on w_arm2.nr_art = nh_arm2.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm3 on w_arm3.nr_art = nh_arm3.waluta 
where t3.indeks = 1 and k3.indeks = 1   
union all  
select 
ifnull((1000.0 + 2 * o4.w7), 0) cnt, 
ifnull((1000.0 - 2 * o4.kor_wzm45), 0) cnt_arm, (w4.kurs / 10000) * nh4.info price, ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm1.info, 0) price_arm1, 
ifnull((w_arm2.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm2.info, 0) price_arm2, 
ifnull((w_arm1.kurs / 10000) * nh_arm3.info, 0) price_arm3, 
osciez4 nr_art_prof, nh4.nazwa, nh4.waluta 
from typyp t4 
inner join Osciezp o4 on t4.osciez4 = o4.nr_art 
left join wzmocn wz1 on wz1.nr_art = o4.wzm1 and 'a' = 'a' 
left join wzmocn wz2 on wz2.nr_art = o4.wzm2 and 'a' = 'b' 
left join wzmocn wz3 on wz3.nr_art = o4.wzm3   and 'a' = 'c' 
inner join profhand ph4 on ph4.nr_art = o4.nr_art 
inner join koloryp k4 on k4.indeks = ph4.idx_koloru 
inner join nhandlo1 nh4 on nh4.nr_art = ph4.nr_art_han 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm1 on nh_arm1.nr_art = wz1.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm2 on nh_arm2.nr_art = wz2.nr_art 
left join nhandlo1 nh_arm3 on nh_arm3.nr_art = wz3.nr_art 
inner join waluty w4 on w4.nr_art = nh4.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm1 on w_arm1.nr_art = nh_arm1.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm2 on w_arm2.nr_art = nh_arm2.waluta 
left join waluty w_arm3 on w_arm3.nr_art = nh_arm3.waluta 
where t4.indeks = 1 and k4.indeks = 1   ) t;
```

And when I try to execute this query it is take to more time to execute (about 2 minutes on Android Emulator). How can I decrease the execution time. Can I use `compileStatement` for this needs ?? Does it compatible with **cursor select** statements ??

Here is execution plan of the query:

```
4|0|0|SEARCH TABLE typyp AS t1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
4|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Osciezp AS o1 USING INDEX osciezp_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|2|2|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz1 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|3|3|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz2 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|4|4|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz3 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|5|5|SEARCH TABLE profhand AS ph1 USING INDEX profhand_NrArtKolor (nr_art=? AND
 idx_koloru=?)
4|6|6|SEARCH TABLE koloryp AS k1 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
4|7|7|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh1 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|8|8|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm1 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|9|9|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm2 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|10|10|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm3 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|11|11|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w1 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|12|12|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm1 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|13|13|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm2 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
4|14|14|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm3 USING COVERING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art
=?)
5|0|0|SEARCH TABLE typyp AS t2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
5|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Osciezp AS o2 USING INDEX osciezp_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|2|2|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz1 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|3|3|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz2 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|4|4|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz3 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|5|5|SEARCH TABLE profhand AS ph2 USING INDEX profhand_NrArtKolor (nr_art=? AND
 idx_koloru=?)
5|6|6|SEARCH TABLE koloryp AS k2 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
5|7|7|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh2 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|8|8|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm1 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|9|9|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm2 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|10|10|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm3 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|11|11|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w2 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|12|12|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm1 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|13|13|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm2 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
5|14|14|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm3 USING COVERING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art
=?)
3|0|0|COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 4 AND 5 (UNION ALL)
6|0|0|SEARCH TABLE typyp AS t3 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
6|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Osciezp AS o3 USING INDEX osciezp_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|2|2|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz1 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|3|3|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz2 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|4|4|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz3 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|5|5|SEARCH TABLE profhand AS ph3 USING INDEX profhand_NrArtKolor (nr_art=? AND
 idx_koloru=?)
6|6|6|SEARCH TABLE koloryp AS k3 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
6|7|7|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh3 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|8|8|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm1 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|9|9|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm2 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|10|10|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm3 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|11|11|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w3 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|12|12|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm1 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|13|13|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm2 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
6|14|14|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm3 USING COVERING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art
=?)
2|0|0|COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 3 AND 6 (UNION ALL)
7|0|0|SEARCH TABLE typyp AS t4 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
7|1|1|SEARCH TABLE Osciezp AS o4 USING INDEX osciezp_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|2|2|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz1 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|3|3|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz2 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|4|4|SEARCH TABLE wzmocn AS wz3 USING COVERING INDEX wzmocn_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|5|5|SEARCH TABLE profhand AS ph4 USING INDEX profhand_NrArtKolor (nr_art=? AND
 idx_koloru=?)
7|6|6|SEARCH TABLE koloryp AS k4 USING INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (rowid=?)
7|7|7|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh4 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|8|8|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm1 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|9|9|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm2 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|10|10|SEARCH TABLE nhandlo1 AS nh_arm3 USING INDEX nhandlo1_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|11|11|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w4 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|12|12|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm1 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|13|13|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm2 USING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art=?)
7|14|14|SEARCH TABLE waluty AS w_arm3 USING COVERING INDEX waluty_nr_art (nr_art
=?)
1|0|0|COMPOUND SUBQUERIES 2 AND 7 (UNION ALL)
0|0|0|SCAN SUBQUERY 1 AS t
```

Comment: Actually you want to increase or decrease execution time ?

Comment: ops, I mean decrease

Comment: Maybe try to rethink your database design if you need such am complicated join, self join, union, ifnull query...

Comment: I agree with @brummfondel. Im not a pro at SQL but looking at your query...seems its gonna take a while to be completed

Comment: I can not redisighn database It is database that used on desktop app and Android app use database imported from this application (There is exist service that convert Sql Server db to sqlite)

Comment: You should a the SQL tag to your question, this is mostly a database issue.

Comment: Maybe sql query is a little bit heavy but on windows desktop with command line util sqlite3.exe it is executed in a moment

Comment: Maybe because a **physical 2600 MHz quad core** is faster than an **emulated 600 MHz single core**?

Comment: As a first thing to notice, **divisions** are slower than **multiplications**. Dividing by 1000 is the same as **multiplying by 0.001** (multiplication by the inverse = division). But the **latter is faster**. On **EVERY CPU** in the world (without entering the details, a multiplication is a series of additions, while division is a series of subtractions and additions are faster than subtractions). Also note that **indexes** can boost your execution performances by **several hundreds times** (**nearly 400x faster** on my tests in my app).

Comment: Try to split the query into peaces and combine the data in Java. That's of course a bad idea if you ask SQL people, however, it may help.

Comment: Your query is not "a little heavy", it's one of the most complex, least-likely to be performant queries I've ever seen, and I've been doing SQL for over 20 years. Unless there's some reason you can't modify the schema after you've converted it from sqlserver, I'd try to redesign it so that its something you can query reasonably.

Comment: @GreyBeardedGeek Then why not provide hints on how to improve it?

Comment: @brummfondel Does it really help ? There are only few new reconnection to db should appear

Comment: Sorry, hit enter, and my comment got added before I finished. Try to preprocess the data as much as you can once, and store that, if you can. Also, as someone mentioned, a number of smaller, simpler queries, with the results combined in Java code may be faster. And make sure that you have good indexes.

Comment: @Vsevywniy It can help but not always. This depends on your data and the structure. If SQL has to read a table several times for your joins reading the required content into a Java list and drop lines might be faster. Not always, this highly depends on the situation.

Comment: Question: what do you want to get by this query and how do you tables look like (columns). Maybe thinking from scratch is a better idea than trying to optimize this big thing.

Comment: Also, something I'm not sure to understand is `and 'a' = 'a'` (always **true**), `and 'a' = 'b'` (always **false**) and `and 'a' = 'c'` (always **false**). Aren't these comparisons **useless** and **time consuming**? Am I missing something?

Comment: @DerGolem the statement that stand to the right hand of the equal are generated from the application and can be one of set 'a', 'b', 'c'. But  it obtain in runtime process.

Comment: Show the output of [EXPLAIN QUERY PLAN](http://www.sqlite.org/eqp.html) for this query.

Comment: @CL. Please find it in the answer's edition.

Comment: No obvious inefficiencies. Try running [ANALYZE](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_analyze.html). But this query cannot be optimized without understanding it.

Comment: @CL. Peple in above comments hint me to split query into smaller peaces for example make 2queries instied something like this `query1 union all query2`. Does can it increase performance in any case? I have tried it in my case but have no obvious effect

Comment: UNION ALL by itself does not decrease performance (it just executes both queries, one after the other). Splitting the query would make sense only if an individual query could be simplified further.